# Rails - Define a couple model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relation

I want to create a "couple" model (`Similarity`) between 2 objects of the same class (`User`).

The order of the `users` in `Similarity` model **does not matter**. In other words, the similarity between user1 and user2 is the same similarity between user2 and user1.

```
class User < AR::Base
end

class Similarity < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :second_user, :class_name => 'User'
  # Some AR attributes here (can not be a HABTM)
end
```

I'm trying to get all the "similar" users of a user. Relations can be defined with

```
class User
  has_many :similarities
  has_many :right_similarities, :class_name => 'Similarity',
                                :foreign_key => 'second_user_id'

  def all_similarities
    return similarities + right_similarities
  end

  has_many :similar_users, :through => :similarities,
                          :source => :second_user
  has_many :right_similar_users, :through => :right_similarities,
                                 :source => :user

  def all_similar_users
    return similar_users + right_similar_users
  end
end
```

But this is clearly not efficient, and hard to read.

How can I declare in "Rails relation way" these relations above ?

Regards

Comment: Why can't it be a HABTM relationship? That would be the "Rails Way."

Comment: There's a good railscast on this:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: @EgeErsoz Because I need a model between the 2 users. It contains some columns describing the similarity.

Comment: @Demosophy Yes, I know it, but it does not describe how to resolve my issues.